# How to set up folders for different versions of a site?

Tags: domains, cpanel

I have a rather large site (50 gigs or so) that I am attempting to do an update on.

The current URL of the site is set up as the 'main domain' in cpanel and the path is home/username/publicHTML.

I have added version 2 of the site in the folder home/username/Version 2.
When I go to the 'domains' option in cpanel I am unable to change the site root (though literally every other domain I own does have the option).

I talked to my host and they said I would need to copy the entire existing site (version 1) to a new folder (home/username/Version 2) and then copy the version 2 to home/username/publicHTML

That seems very wrong.

Is there a simple way I can set it up so that I can change the document root of my 'main domain' without having to go through terminal, etc (which is what google says).

Comment: Does your host give you the "change primary domain" option in cPanel? https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/domain-names/how-do-i-change-the-main-domain-name-on-my-account/

Comment: There isn't an option in cPanel's interface to change the document root for your main domain, you'd need to use SSH as per the instructions [here](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/change-root-directory-for-the-main-domain.592551/). You should have an SSH application in cPanel though, as pictured [here](https://netmow.com/how-to-change-root-folder-for-primary-domain-in-cpanel/). If that's not letting you `cd` to `/var/cpanel/userdata/USERNAME/`, then you'll need to request your hosting provider to make the change for you.